# Why do I get "invalid multibyte char" in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to setup a mailer with SMTP and getting the following error (from console):

```
SyntaxError (/Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/prelaunch/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:6: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/prelaunch/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ']'
    headers[‘X-MC-Track’] = "opens, clicks"
             ^):
  app/models/user.rb:37:in `send_welcome_email'
```

user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "remindeal@gmail.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Invitation Request Received")
    headers[‘X-MC-Track’] = "opens, clicks"
    headers[‘X-MC-GoogleAnalytics’] = "example.com"
    headers[‘X-MC-Tags’] = "welcome"
  end
end
```

User.rb:

```
35 def send_welcome_email
36    unless self.email.include?('@example.com')
37      UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby only accepts single quote, double quote and backquote to quote strings. Each of them has different meaning.

Since you're quoting keys of `headers` hash with multibyte forward quote and backquote, ruby emit the error. I guess you copy pasted some of prettified source codes on some web site.

You can replace above source like this, using single quotes:

```
headers['X-MC-Track'] = "opens, clicks"
headers['X-MC-GoogleAnalytics'] = "example.com"
headers['X-MC-Tags'] = "welcome"
```

Note that, typically, using symbols (`:like_this`) for a hash key is recommended, but for the case like above, you need to use either single quote or double quotes, since it contains `-` as the part of the keys.

Comment: sorry so just change to "@example.com"?

Comment: This link might help you http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-prelaunch-signup.html

Comment: Those aren't backticks, they're "smart"/"curly" quotes.

Comment: The line with 'open clicks' looks like actually backquotes, isn't it?

Comment: @shigeya Nope. ``‘ ` ’`` the one in the middle is a backtick, the other two are proper "curly" quotes. Obviously the three are all unique. Further, a backtick is valid ASCII, but the other two are not.

Comment: Are you talking in Ruby language or not?

I think you've edited the question title wrong. Ruby's special characters for quoting is single quote pair, double quote pair or backquote pairs. No mismatches. As far as I know, never allowed to use multibyte special characters in that context. I believe author wrongly used quote that is the point.

Comment: Ah, may be I need to revise my answer including the point you raised. I'll do that later today.